# Automate Chrome cast with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-chrome, automation, uicontrol

I have a Python 2.7 script that should cast mp3 audio from Windows 10 to Chromecast audio devices through Google Chrome browser.

It does the following using Send Keys (keyboard and mouse automation) from the PyWinAuto module:

1. Open Google Chrome maximized
2. Click the "Customize and control Google Chrome" menu on the right
3. Selects "Cast.."
4. Selects a casting group
5. Inputs local address of mp3 in the address bar and hits Enter

It involves using time.sleep() a lot and has many problems as an experienced programmer would imagine. So I'm looking for a pythonic way of accomplishing the same result.

P.S: A cross-platform solution is much appreciated (especially for Raspberry Pi). And I can learn anything you suggest, even if it's not Python. Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid there is no open-source cross-platform tool for GUI automation supporting all desktop OSes simultaneously. On Windows it can be done using pyuwinauto (`backend='uia'`). `SendKeys` is not reliable because of timing issues as you mentioned. But pywinauto handles timings smoothly if you use class `Application` or `Desktop`. My student wrote example that drags and drops file from explorer.exe to Chrome: [test_explorer_google_drive.py](https://github.com/vasily-v-ryabov/ui-automation-course/blob/master/02_google_drive_Murashov/test_explorer_google_drive.py). Hope it will be useful.

Comment: [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) explains the core concept, so I'd recommend reading it first.